# Standard Webpack config vs vue-cli config

Tags: webpack, vuejs2

I have a vue project that currently I build with webpack using standard webpack.config.js style files. Now I want to create create a webcomponent using

```
vue-cli-service build --target wc --name my-element dummy.vue
```

However doing that I now get

> ```
> ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                                        23:27:28
>  error  in ./src/frontend/ui/dummy.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&shadow
>
> Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (13:3)
> File was processed with these loaders:
>  * ../../../AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js
>  * ../../../AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js
> You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> |
> | export default class Dummy extends Vue{
> >    @Prop()
> |    msg: string;
> | }
>
>  @ ./src/frontend/ui/dummy.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&shadow 1:0-304 1:320-323 1:325-626 1:325-626
>  @ ./src/frontend/ui/dummy.vue?shadow
>  @ C:/Users/.../AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/build/entry-wc.js
>
>  ERROR  Build failed with errors.
> ```

So I wonder how can I tell vue-cli-service to use my existing webpack config file to make sure it is loaded correctly instead of whatever config it has internally

Answer (score 0):

That's because the generated code for the the component contains `@Prop` (as you see in the error output).

This syntax is decorator syntax. You need to configure your webpack.config.js to handle decorators. You will need to use Babel for this, by using `babel-loader`, and [`babel-plugin-proposal-decorators`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-decorators)

> how can I tell vue-cli-service to use my existing webpack config file to make sure it is loaded correctly instead of whatever config it has internally

Here's how to configure vue-cli's webpack config:

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html